# URL friendly separator to split multiple values for a query string param

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, query-string

I need to pass multiple values as one param in the query string. Is there a better way to do it than the below example? I do not want to use session to send these values from page to page.

For example: http://www.mywebapp.com/Products.aspx?CategoryIds=45|29|98

Is pipes the best way to do something like this? I noticed they get turned into % symbols but it does not mess up my code when I do:

```
Request["CategoryIds"];
```

Comment: You could use dashes `-`.

Comment: This in not a really question - dashes (-), commas(,), pipes(|) ... whatever, they can do the same result if you decode the URL carefully. And also, you already know you can pass them safely by `Request["CategoryIds"]`, I think your current solution is good enough.

Comment: What is the issue if your code is able read the query string properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar situation and I am using comma to separate the numbers in query string.

Even in your case, looks like the CategoryIds are all numbers. So, I think comma should work for you.

[image]

And the URL will look something like this: `http://localhost:62100/Contact.aspx?CategoryIds=1,2,3`